# How to install ZIP-based OS in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, iso-image, zip

I'm trying to run [LineageOS](https://download.lineageos.org/) in VirtualBox. I have already downloaded the ZIP-file and tried to create a bootable ISO-file of the content with mkisofs. This was not successful because VirtualBox could not find a bootable medium (before booting I added the ISO to the optical drive).

Comment: Did you try to follow the instruction for Android?

Comment: I couldn't find a instruction where the OS was shipped as a ZIP. They always used ISO.

Comment: What file have you downloaded exactly?

Comment: LineageOS is a continuation of the CyanogenMod project. To this date there was no version of CM for PC (i.e. no VM version as well). There are a few Android x86 clones for desktop computers, though.

Comment: I downloaded this file: `lineage-14.1-20170125-nightly-oneplus3-signed.zip`. When I unzip it I see these files and directories: `boot.img`, `file_context.bin`, `firmware-update`, `install`, `META-INF`, `META-INF`, `recovery`, `system`. I know that LineageOS is not build for the PC but I want to try it out without the need of flashing it to my phone. It is possible to run the original Android image in VirtualBox although it is not build for this purpose. That is the reason why I thought this would work the same way with LineageOS. But I don't know what to do with the ZIP-file in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment, you say

> I know that LineageOS is not build for the PC but I want to try it out without the need of flashing it to my phone. It is possible to run the original Android image in VirtualBox although it is not build for this purpose.

As you point out, LineageOS is not built for the Intel x86 architecture used in PC processors, but for the ARM architecture used in most mobile devices.

When you say the "original Android image" can be run in VirtualBox, perhaps you're thinking of the [Android x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android-x86) project? This is a version of Android that has been modified to run on x86 processors. Similarly, in order to run on x86 processors (and in VirtualBox) someone would need to port the LineageOS code itself and create a compatible build. You won't be able to run the OnePlus 3 version in VirtualBox as it is built for ARM processors.

If you want to try it out without flashing it to your phone, perhaps you could use some sort of Android Device Emulator for the PC?

Comment: Quick note: you can't run a custom ROM in an emulator (AVD or any other emulator available for PC). ROMs are devices-specific, and nobody publishes ROMs versions for emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there IS a LineageOS build for x86 PCs - including emulators (such as vmWare and VirtualBox).  You are thinking (like all too many) that x86 is not a valid target - despite x86 being not only a valid generic target, but a Google-supported target - going all the way back to Lollipop.  What has been lacking is NOT the support in Android - but in the generic x86-emulation support community (neither vmWare or Oracle VirtualBox supports Android  as a guest); you have to make VirtualBox (for example) think that Android is Linux to get it to run at all.  Alternatively, you can take that same ISO and run it on a USB stick (that is something that I personally have done since the days of Lollipop-x86).

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This post is more of a commentary than an actionable solution to the question.  Can you make the "how" more explicit?